# conditional value of hidden field in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

This is my ASP Mark Up for radio button list

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>

        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbcourse" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Height="54px" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" style="text-align: left; font-weight: 700;" Width="385px">
            <asp:ListItem >BA</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>BSC</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>BSCN</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>BCOM</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
   </ContentTemplate>

</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

this is the markup for hidden field

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hffee" runat="server" Value="122" />
```

this is the sql add parameter value for hffee

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hffee", Val(hffee.Value))
```

Now i need if user clicks say on BA radio list item the value of HFFEE which is hidden field and whose value in property is set to nill shall be say 1200 if user selects BSC then the value of hffee shall be 1500 i nut shell i need dynamic value of hidden field which will get stored on sql server on btn submit

i am changing the check box like enable disable checked true false etc on this radio button list 
on v.b code on the event rbcourse_selected index change  which is radio button list
i am just writing

```
Protected Sub rbcourse_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rbcourse.SelectedIndexChanged

    If rbcourse.SelectedIndex = "0" Then (0 is the item value of BA)
        ge.Checked = True  (ge is the text name of check box and it is working)
```

on that same manner i need

```
If rbcourse.SelectedIndex = "0" Then (0 is the item value of BA)
 then
```

hffe.value="1200" like this

Comment: I am a bit confused about what you are asking, can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: i will edit my post than may be u will get my question

Comment: @ Ahmed Salman Tahir- i have elaborated the question plz have alook

Comment: Do you always have the fixed values that you want to send in case of selection? I mean against BA it will always be 1200, against BSC 1500 and so on? Or can these change?

Comment: @Ahmed Salman Tahir--yes it will always every time i select BA if it will change then that will be always but only one number. Actually the value is admission fee if Some one clicks BA the admission fee must be say 2500. if B.Sc the value which is admission fee for BSC must be say 2800

Comment: @Ahmed Salman Tahir-- i mean to say it will be static. that will not change

Comment: Then you can use the statement that you yourself mentioned: hffe.Value = "1200". I am sorry but I still don't understand what's stopping you to achieve what you are looking for?!

Comment: but on submit it is storing 0 in database and when i am setting permanent value in properties of hffee it is getting stored as value mentioned. I think it the event problem on what event the hffee shall get stored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I tried and got the fee at button click:

```
Enum AdmissionFee
    BA = 1200
    BSC = 1800
    BSCN = 2100
    BCOM = 2500
End Enum

Protected Sub rbcourse_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rbcourse.SelectedIndexChanged
    If rbcourse.SelectedIndex = "0" Then
        Me.hffee.Value = Convert.ToString(AdmissionFee.BA)
    ElseIf rbcourse.SelectedIndex = "1" Then
        Me.hffee.Value = Convert.ToString(AdmissionFee.BSC)
    ElseIf rbcourse.SelectedIndex = "2" Then
        Me.hffee.Value = Convert.ToString(AdmissionFee.BSCN)
    ElseIf rbcourse.SelectedIndex = "3" Then
        Me.hffee.Value = Convert.ToString(AdmissionFee.BCOM)
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim fee As Integer
    fee = Convert.ToInt32(Me.hffee.Value)

    If Me.RdoGender.SelectedIndex = "1" Then
        fee += 750
    End If

    If Me.FE.Checked Then
        fee += 110
    End If

    If Me.dropboard.SelectedIndex > 0 Then
        fee += 100
    End If
End Sub
```

Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: thanx brother it worked but i need some logic  in that fee value. i.e if user in form selected gender ="F" female then to every course value 750 shall be added to the base value menas if for BCOM fee is 2500 and gender is F then it should be 3250 by adding 750 to it as bus fee

Comment: @arshad - I have updated my reply and added the bus fee logic on button click...please check

Comment: Thanx for your valuable efforts so far it is not adding the value of bus fee let me give you the exact asp markup for gender radioButtonlist<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RdoGender" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="176px" AutoPostBack="True">
                        <asp:ListItem>Male</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Female</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>

Comment: Thanx for your valuable efforts so far it is not adding the value of bus fee let me give you the exact asp markup for gender      <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RdoGender runat=server" 
 <asp:ListItem>Male</asp:ListItem><asp:ListItem>Female</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>.   Sorry i forgot to mention there are two more thing  there is a table (id=artstable)  ,one of the  td of table contains the check box FE if that is checked hffee shall be also added with 110 along with adm fee and busfee , 2nd there is a dropdown id= dropboard if SelectedIndex is not equal to "0" add 100 to hffee

Comment: thanx for your reply but the three conditions added by you did not add to hffee field only BA = 1200
        BSC = 1800
        BSCN = 2100
        BCOM = 2500 conditions are working i mean to say conditions if rdogender is Female, check box fe and dropboard >0 are not adding to the hffee but

Comment: In that case I suggest you debug your code step-by-step. That is the best option right now as you have the complete code fully setup and that will enhance your learning too

Comment: shall i forward this form to you on mail so that u will check it there.if yes plz communicate your e-mail id

Comment: By step by step I mean to debug your code. Plus, I don't think it's a good idea to send it to me rather ask your question on StackOverflow and you will get a response from one of the many people here